# rewrite rule with 3 parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How do i use rewrite rule with 3 parameteres?
like:

```
RewriteRule example/$/$/$ example.php?x=$1&y=$2&z=$3
```

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Ok ;

i found the answer :

```
RewriteRule ex/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) ex.php?x=$1&y=$2&z=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ex/([^/]+)/([^/]+) ex.php?x=$1&y=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ex/([^/]+) ex.php?x=$1 [L]
```

thanks to Tim Cooper for editing help.